# Strtok deletes last char before delimiter

Tags: c, file, input, strtok

I'm trying to read a file using fgets and tokenise it with strtok but somehow im losing the last char of the first token(title). Ive been trying for a while to fix this but cant seem to do it any help is appreciated. I've though of adding a char just before the delimiter but im not quite sure how to implement that.

```
char line[201];
char *title;
int year;
char *age;
char *genre;
int lenght; 
float rating;
while ((fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp)) != NULL){
    strtok(line,"\"");
    title = line;
    year = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
    age = strtok(NULL,",");
    memmove(age, age+1, strlen(age));
    genre = strtok(NULL,",");
    memmove(genre, genre+1, strlen(genre));
    lenght = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
    rating = atof(strtok(NULL,","));
    x = new_film(title,year,age,genre,lenght,rating);
    Insert(root, x);
}
```

file data looks like this :

"The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",1966,"APPROVED","Western",161,8.9
"Memento",2000,"R","Mystery/Thriller",113,8.5

output looks like this:

The Good, the Bad and the Ugl,1966,APPROVED,Western,161,8.9

Comment: Cannot reproduce from code shown (although it leaves in a few undesirable `"` marks). It must be in the code you have not shown. For example, I get `"The Good, the Bad and the Ugly` so my guess is one of those functions is trying to strip the quotes by guesswork, which have already been removed.

Comment: Your use of `strtok` is horrible - you never check its return value, and you ignore its first return value - that is why your titles begin with `"`. And all that nasty string shifting?

Comment: `strtok(line,"\""); title = line;` --> `title = strtok(line,"\"");`

Comment: @WeatherVane im using memmove to remove the leading " and trailing " gets removed by strtok although it shouldn't? And i do now its horrible i just hacked it and will return to make it cleaner and nicer

Comment: @BLUEPIXY im getting a segmentation fault

Comment: That is not my fault.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I wasn't getting any with my code ? thx for trying anyways

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem (as this question is doing) there are certain requrements: 1) post code that cleanly compiles (including the `#include` statements)  The posted code does not even come close to compiling.

Comment: Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `strtok()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `title = line;` just copies a pointer, suggest using: `strdup()`

Comment: note: the 'title' has a leading delimiter,  That leading delimiter needs to be stepped over. otherwise the first call to `strtok()` will return a pointer to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You have a confusion of ignoring the return value from `strtok` and trying to fiddle the strings it is separating. I suggest this (although you should always check for bad data formatting, for example when `strtok` returns `NULL`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[201];
    char *title;
    int year;
    char *age;
    char *genre;
    int lenght; 
    float rating;
    while ((fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)) != NULL){

        title = strtok(line, "\"");                 // use this value
        year = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\",\n"));         // added delimiters
        age = strtok(NULL, "\",\n");
        genre = strtok(NULL, "\",\n");
        lenght = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\",\n"));
        rating = (float)atof(strtok(NULL, "\",\n"));

        printf("%s\n", title);
        printf("%d\n", year);
        printf("%s\n", age);
        printf("%s\n", genre);
        printf("%d\n", lenght);
        printf("%f\n", rating);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
1966
APPROVED
Western
161
8.900000

Memento
2000
R
Mystery/Thriller
113
8.500000
```

Comment: Actually the problem was in my new struct function when i was copying the string nonetheless, thanks a lot I would have probably wasted quite some time to find this

Answer (score 0):

note: the 'title' has a leading delimiter,

you should be VERY careful when the next character to be check is a delimiter.

Strongly suggest always use a delimiter of `,` (comma) for your current data example.

If you want to (later) remove any ``"` (double quotes) then the surrounding double quotes will still be there to and can be easily removed.

Lets remember that `strtok()` replaces the delimiter with a NUL byte, so the first call (in the posted code) to `strtok()` will have already trimmed the trailing double quote